# How to fix active-class problem in minicalendar with calendar / exposed filters

Tags: 7, views, theming, datetime

I have a calendar view for events. The events are categorized by taxonomy terms. I use the minicalendar for the selection of days and filter the result list with an exposed list of the categories.

This is all working fine.

But user interface lacks a bit of coherence. There's no indication of which day is picked on the minicalendar (which only has a class for "today").

This [snippet](https://www.drupal.org/node/1545818#comment-8826413) helped me getting an "active" class for the datebox, so users can see, which date they have chosen:

```
<?php
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_calendar_datebox(&$vars) {
  $url = $vars['url']; // The (absolute) URL of the item.
  $current = url(request_path(), array('absolute' => TRUE)); // The absolute URL of the page being viewed.
  if ($url == $current) {
    $classes = explode(' ', $vars['class']); // Extract the current classes as a list.
    $classes[] = 'active'; // Add 'active' to the class list.
    $vars['class'] = implode(' ', $classes); // Concatenate and attach the updated class list.
  }
}
?>
```

But here's the problem: when i select a taxonomy term, the url changes from:

```
/myview/2014-11-27
```

to

```
/myview?field_category_tid_selective=8 (e.g)
```

and my active class is gone.
How can i achieve that the class stays, even when a filter is active on the results?

Any help appreciated!
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next, that work without using urls, using *second argument*:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_calendar_datebox(&$vars) {
  $arg = arg();

  // If no second argument provided - that's mean today. 
  // Please check how argument date supplied for next day: 2014-12-01 or 2014-12-1 and change date() to appropriate.
  $url_date = empty($arg[1]) ? date('Y-m-d') : $arg[1]; 

  if ($vars['date'] == $url_date) {
    $classes = explode(' ', $vars['class']); // Extract the current classes as a list.
    $classes[] = 'active'; // Add 'active' to the class list.
    $vars['class'] = implode(' ', $classes); // Concatenate and attach the updated class list.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's almost working! But the active class is assigned to "today" when a filter is selected, instead of the day the user has selected. So right now if i choose the 27th of Nov and select a filter, the active class is assigned to 25th of Nov (today). The argument format is correct, it's Y-m-d...

Comment: I think the problem is, when the filter is applied the url has no date argument no more, but somehow stores which date is selected.

If i select a filter and change to another day, the active class is assigned correct, until i change the filter again. Then the active class is gone again...

Comment: I assume then you select filter, it's loss current selected date. Is it?

Comment: Yes, correct...

Comment: I mean, if you selecting filter and in url no date, it shouldn't show to you some date, only today. Is it?

Comment: Nikit, that is correct, when the calendar page is loaded for the first time, it shows the date of today (beeing active).

Comment: This answer at least helped partially so i rewarded the bounty to you. I was hoping for more attention on this anyhow...

Comment: can you pastebin exported views with minicalendar?

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra parameters to a path if you use Page Manager (part of [ctools](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools)) and [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels).

1. Go to `structure -> pages` in the admin menu (`admin/structure/pages`) and click +add custom page
2. Set the [Path] to something like `myview/%selected-date`
3. Set the [Variant type] to `Panel`, don't worry about the [Optional features]
4. Choose a `one column` layout (for starters at least)
5. In the content area click the cog and choose `add content`

[image: content area and cog]

6. Find your view and place it as content

Voila!

Now you can use your current method to set the url to `myview/2014-11-27` and when they choose a filter it will look like `myview/2014-11-27?field_category_tid_selective=8`.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: Darvanen, sorry i couldn't review your answer because i had no time but I'll definitely look into it. Thanks for your answer...

Comment: It's all good mate, it is simply an alternative.